# Generate Dynamic Pages With ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently programming classic asp and have my own CMS and it's a good one but I'd like to move it to c#.net meanwhile. (customers don't like this old language anymore)
on my current CMS I generate Pages physically with ASP FSO(filesystem object).
so my question is should i use this method at asp.net too? I reviewed some .NET cms and realized that they don't build pages physically.

For example after working with a CMS noticed that When I type http://localhost/PageName.aspx in address bar actually it's still in default.aspx but it regenerated page with contents that belong to PageName.aspx's PageID at database.

Comment: Theres no need to generate the actual pages and save them as files. Best and easiest way (imo) is to just serve them dynamically and let asp.net handle any caching you may need.

Answer (score 2):

With ASP.NET it is no longer necessary to create files physically. Save the content in a database, use asp.net controls to show this content and use the asp.net caching techniques to load content without a rountrip to the database - like any other cms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Also look into using an existing CMS.  There are many of them out there and lots of intel in them.  Much cheaper to reuse than to create a new one.

Comment: As a product I gotta create my own CMS ... you know I'm not a customer but I have my clients :)

Comment: @Kai : Thank you for tip. is any simple cms or any tutorial which use these techniques. until now I think briefly a Paragraph table is required in order to hold Page contents and another table to hold Paragraph details(like modules that used or html contents, ...).
But still don't get how to know which items must get retrieved from db when user type http://localhost/page.aspx